# Using spring boot for end2end web services tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws

I created a simple web service using spring-ws and spring-boot. I compile it and i run it and it works. I am able to access wsdl etc.

Then I thought I can use spring-boot for end2end tests like this:

```
public class TimesheetWsShould {

    @Before
    public void return0ElementsIfNoHoursWasBookedInMonth() {
        Main.main(new String[] {}); // this is where spring-boot starts
    }

    @Test
    public void actualTest(){
       //actual test using spring-ws template to consume web service.
    }
}
```

The Main class is where spring-boot is doing it's magic.
Unfortunatelly durring the startup an exception is thrown and it does not tell me anything usefull. Googling for similar problems gives no satisfying results.

The question is why when I run the whole package everything works but invoking it  programatically from test doesn't.  I assume there is additional configuration done durring build process.

Below is the error message I get running my tests:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultMethodEndpointAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.defaultMethodEndpointAdapter()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.setCustomMethodArgumentResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V`

Comment: Why not simply use the [integration testing support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications) in Spring Boot instead of trying to (re)invent your own?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks I was doing that the harder way :).
BTW I managed to solve my issue with additional beans in my configuration but that's a lot more tedious than adding couple annotations to my test class ;)